# Spring Boot Google Maps SAXParseException

Tags: javascript, java, spring, google-maps, spring-boot

I'm working with spring boot and try to add a Google Maps in my view. Here is what I try to do:

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/map", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String map(Model model) { return "map"; }
```

**View** (resources/templates/map.html)

```
<script async="async" defer="defer"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=/*mykey*/&callback=initMap;">
</script>
```

**Error**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Referenz zu Entity "callback" muss mit dem Begrenzungszeichen ";" enden.
```

How you can see I have added an ";" behind the callback methode, but it is stil not working (when you work not with spring boot it is also working without the ";").

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try replacing & with &amp;

Comment: it works! perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `&` with `&amp;` in your url.